# How to work with nulls in docutils

Tags: python, doctest

I'm trying to run doctest on a function that works with nulls. But doctest doesn't seem to like the nulls...

```
def do_something_with_hex(c):
    """
    >>> do_something_with_hex('\x00')
    '\x00'
    """
return repr(c)

import doctest
doctest.testmod()
```

I'm seeing these errors

```
Failed example:
    do_something_with_hex(' ')
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\doctest.py", line 1254, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
    TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
**********************************************************************
```

What can I do to allow nulls in test cases like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could escape all of the backslashes, or alternatively change your docstring to a [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
def do_something_with_hex(c):
    r"""
    >>> do_something_with_hex('\x00')
    '\x00'
    """
    return repr(c)
```

With the `r` prefix on the string a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and *all backslashes are left in the string*.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\\x` instead of `\x`. When you write `\x`, the Python interpreter interprets it as a null byte, and the null byte itself gets inserted into the docstring. E.g.,:

```
>>> def func(x):
...     """\x00"""
...
>>> print func.__doc__     # this will print a null byte

>>> def func(x):
...     """\\x00"""
...
>>> print func.__doc__
\x00
```